# Does asp.net makes a http/soap request on events?

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET, and was wondering how the events works.

I have a on change event on a text input that immediatly fires the event on my server file, how does that work ? ASP.NET makes a request to my server the momment the event is triggered on the client ? If so, that request is an HTTP or SOAP ?

Comment: You are probably talking about Webforms? It does a form post (PostBack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a full page post-back, and hence a http post-back.

One of the issues that "many" people have noted and lamented over the years is that Webforms tends with great ease to build pages that with "great" ease result in many post-backs.

So, I can't say all that often I have used a text box to trigger a whole page post back, but it certainly is possible.

So, any post back will start what we call that round trip.

The page is posted up to the server. Code behind runs, page is processed and rendered, and THEN sent back down to the client side.

So, having to suffer a whole page post-back for JUST some "change" event in a text box is considered by most "too heavy" of a task and requires too much bandwidth, and can often hurt performance of such web pages.

However, you can convert the event and the post-back into a ajax like experience for the user (And not suffer a whole page post-back).

And most interesting is this ability to avoid a whole page post-back does not require you to write any client-side browser code in JavaScript.

So, let's have a page in which we enter a first name, and then last name. However, typing in either text box will trigger the on-change event, and update a label that has first name + last name result of the two textboxes.

And for good measure, we also have another label that updates the time every one second. You will note that you can freely type into the first name fields, and they don't get messed up by the label that shows the time.

These so-called update panels in web forms are how this magic occurs, and note how we did not write one line of JavaScript, and note how we did not have to setup some ajax calls and web methods to the server.

So, at very top of the web page, right after "form" tag, we drop in the ScriptManager.

And then we drag in an update panel.

Place you markup inside of the ContentTemplate.

For one of the update panels, we have the time of the page updating every second. Note how you are free to type in the first name, and then the last name fields during the timer update.

Hence both parts of the page are running independent of each other.
(You not seeing nor suffering a full page post-back)

So, this markup:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<div style="padding:35px">

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" 
    UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <h3>Current Server Date and Time</h3>
        <h4 id="mydate" runat="server"></h4>

        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" 
            Interval="1000"
            OnTick="Timer1_Tick"                
            >
        </asp:Timer>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<br />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server"
    UpdateMode="Conditional"
    >
    <ContentTemplate>

        <div style="float:left">
            <h4>Enter First Name</h4>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server"
                OnTextChanged="txtFirst_TextChanged"
                AutoPostBack="true">
            </asp:TextBox>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:40px">
            <h4>Enter Last Name</h4>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server"
                OnTextChanged="txtLast_TextChanged"
                AutoPostBack="true" >
            </asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;margin-left:40px">
            <h4>First and Last name result</h4>
            <asp:Label ID="lblFullName" runat="server"
                Font-Size="Larger">
            </asp:Label>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And code behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim s As String =
        DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM dd yyyy") & " " &
        DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")

    mydate.InnerHtml = $"<i>{s}</i>"

End Sub

Protected Sub txtFirst_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    lblFullName.Text = txtFirst.Text & " " & txtLast.Text

End Sub

Protected Sub txtLast_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    lblFullName.Text = txtFirst.Text & " " & txtLast.Text
End Sub
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

Note how the time part updates, and how I am able to edit, type and freely enter text in the first name and last name fields, but NOT suffer nor see a post-back.

Do keep in mind that while the update panel system seems like magic?

The page life cycle for EACH update panel does exist, and in EACH case, any post-back inside of the update panel will cause the page on-load event to run each time. And thus, for a simple button click (in an update panel, or outside of one), then the page load event runs first, and then the event runs. However, the WHOLE page is now not being posted back to the server.

As above shows, we were able to have two parts of the page update, update independent of each other. More amazing is we did not write any client-side JavaScript for this miracle to occur!